# Which string table does the section header list point to?

Tags: linux, file, binary, elf

An Elf file can have multiple String Tables however the list of Section Headers sh_name field is an index into this table. How does the file know which string table to refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two string tables in an ELF file:

1. `.strtab`, which contains the symbols' names.
2. `.shstrtab` (**S**ection **H**eader **Str**ing **Tab**le), which contains the sections' names.

If you want to use `sectionHeader.sh_name`, then you're probably looking for the section's name in the `.shstrtab` table. It can be obtained using the following code (obviously for 64 bit):

```
Elf64_Ehdr* header = (Elf64_Ehdr*) map;
Elf64_Shdr* stringTable = (Elf64_Shdr*) (map + header->e_shoff +
                             header->e_shstrndx * header->e_shentsize);        
char* sectionName = map + stringTable->sh_offset + sectionHeader->sh_name;

// 'map' is a pointer to the beginning of your mapped ELF file
```

*Thank you **@Employed Russian** for pointing a better way to retrieve the header's size.*

Comment: It is generally wrong to use `sizeof(Elf64_Shdr)` -- you should use `header->e_shentsize` instead (the two often match, but don't have to).

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thank you! It is more generalized, hence a better way to calculate it. I've edited my answer, for next generations' sake